# React native - how to keep screen on ? Without expo <SOLUTION>

Tags: java, react-native

Do you need keep your phone keep on for coding  better ?

In `MainActivity.java` we usually have this

**File:** `MainActivity.java`

```
package com.client;

import com.facebook.react.ReactActivity;

public class MainActivity extends ReactActivity {
  
   /**
   * Returns the name of the main component registered from JavaScript. This is used to schedule
   * rendering of the component.
   */

  @Override
  protected String getMainComponentName() {
    return "client";
  }


}
```

You can add some lines for keep your phone always on for coding better, this lines the code won't let your phone wake down.

**Solution**:

```
package com.client;

import com.facebook.react.ReactActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.WindowManager;

public class MainActivity extends ReactActivity {
  
   /**
   * Returns the name of the main component registered from JavaScript. This is used to schedule
   * rendering of the component.
   */

  @Override
  protected String getMainComponentName() {
    return "client";
  }

  @Override
  protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    this.getWindow().
      addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_KEEP_SCREEN_ON);
  }

}
```

Comment: this doesn't sound like a question at all.

Comment: this is a solution!

Comment: If this is a solution, then you should rewrite your **question** to an actual question and post the solution as an **answer** to that question.